# What do these elements in Android Build.Gradle (Module:App) do?

Tags: android, gradle, bitcoinj

I tried to add this BitcoinJ library **'org.bitcoinj:bitcoinj-core:0.15'** dependencies but it fail every time I ran it.
Then I found a solution from here.
I needed to add these elements in the module, which are

```
dataBinding {
    enabled true
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'lib/x86_64/darwin/libscrypt.dylib'
    exclude 'lib/x86_64/freebsd/libscrypt.so'
    exclude 'lib/x86_64/linux/libscrypt.so'
}
```

It wouldn't fail if I remove dataBinding and compileOptions elements.

Can anyone please explain what these elements really do.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: `packagingOptions` is for excluding same files if more than one binaries containg the same file during packaging . This will resolve the packaging build error . `compileOptions` will enable you to use specified java version . And `dataBinding` is for [dataBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding).

Comment: Thanks ADM,
This is really help:)